# How do you add bare custom scopes in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito, hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I am trying to define the following custom scopes in AWS Cognito (`launch`, `aud`, `offline_access`, `online_access`, `fhirUser`). These scopes are for [SMART on FHIR.](http://hl7.org/fhir/smart-app-launch/scopes-and-launch-context/index.html#quick-start)

However, I am only able to define custom scopes of the form `<resourceServerIdentifier>/<scopeName>` by defining resources servers.

I want to define "bare" scopes that either include the `resourceIdentifier` by itself or `scopeName` by itself.

Indeed the [AWS Cognito docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html) do specify that in requesting a scope a client must include the full identifier for the scope.

"Bare" scopes are such a common use in OAuth that I believe there should be a work around to support it. Has anyone been able to resolve this?

Comment: what is not very clear to me it's if you want the resource server anyway or if you are using it because you are trying a workaround for setting up custom scopes. If you don't want to use a resource server, I think that you need to use a combination of scopes from (openid fhirUser (or openid profile)), there is a suggested project on aws documentation, maybe you have found this already [https://github.com/awslabs/fhir-works-on-aws-deployment]

Comment: @stamstam I wanted to create scopes for `launch`, `offline_access` and `online_access`. These are "bare" because there is no separate identifier and scopeName (like `launch/patient`). Thanks for flagging the AWS labs project. Unfortunately, it doesn't broach the SMART on FHIR launch sequences that use `scope: launch`, thereby side-stepping the issue of "bare" scopes, and some other Cognito limitations.

Comment: Hi @rmharrison, did you ever get anywhere with bare scopes?